# Checking a proof about connected G and its connected complementary

Tags: graph-theory

Help me understand proof of this theorem.

**Theorem:** If $G$ is a connected graph with $n$ vertices and if $\Delta(G) < \frac{n}{2}$ then the complement of
$G$ is connected.

I tried to prove this by picking an arbitrary vertex in $G$ and naming it $a$.  Then we can write $\deg a=t$, which according to the assumption and the fact that every vertex in the graph has degree less than or equal to $\Delta(G)$ means that we can write $\deg a=t \leq \Delta(G)<\frac{n}{2}$, so $t<\frac{n}{2}$.

By logic, the degree of $a$ in $\overline G$ is $n-t-1$.
So if we replace the upper bound on $t$ in $\deg_{\overline G}(a)=n-t-1$, then $\deg_{\overline G}(a) < n-\frac{n}{2}-1$. So, because every vertex has degree greater than or equal to $\delta(G)$, we can write $\delta(\overline G) \leq \deg_{\overline G}(a) < \frac{n}{2}-1$, so it’s also true that $\delta(G)<\frac{n}{2}-1<\frac{n}{2}-2 = \frac{n-1}{2}$.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong ?
Because I should come to $\delta(\overline G)>\frac{n-1}{2}$ in order to come to the connectedness of $\overline G$ (by using another theorem).

Which conclusion am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I found what I'm wrong about . If we replace $t$ with its upper bound in $\deg_{\overline G}(a) =n-t-1$,
the $t$ has negative sign, so it would be like $$\deg_{\overline G}(a) > n-\frac{n}{2}-1 \tag{1}.$$
But there is also a problem.

We know that
$$\delta (\overline G) \leq \deg_{\overline G}(a). \tag{2}$$
How can we conclude from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that
$\delta(\overline G)>\frac{n}{2}-1$?
It doesn’t seem logical.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $G'$ be the complement of $G$. Suppose for sake of contradiction that $G'$ is not connected. We can then partition $G'$ into $k>1$ components. Consider the smallest such component $C$. It has some size $c\leq \frac{n}{2}$. Each vertex of $C$ is disconnected from the other components. In the complement of $G'$ (which is $G$), then, each vertex of $C$ has an edge connecting it to each vertex outside of $C$, which implies that each vertex of $C$ has degree $\geq n-c \geq \frac{n}{2}$, contradicting the assumption that $\Delta(G)<\frac{n}{2}$. So in fact $G'$ must be connected.

Your approach was to pick an arbitrary *vertex*. This proof demonstrates that it is better to think about an arbitrary *component*. The condition of connectedness, after all, lets you infer things more easily about components than about vertices.